# PHP `mbstring` installing problem in Deepin OS-Linux

Tags: php, linux, laravel

`sudo apt-get install php8.2-mbstring`

When I run this command for installing php-mbstring I get this output

---

```
SYED_AMIR_ALI@amirali:~$ sudo apt-get install php8.2-mbstring
[sudo] password for SYED_AMIR_ALI: 
Verification successful
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php8.2-mbstring : Depends: libonig4 (>= 5.9.5) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

I want to install Laravel Breeze. Without php mbstring, when I try to install Laravel breeze using `composer require laravel/breeze --dev` this command after `php artisan breeze:install` this command, then I faced that problem.

```
 SYED_AMIR_ALI@amirali:~/Desktop/laravel-rtk-query$ php artisan breeze:install
 Which stack would you like to install?
 Error 
 Call to undefined function `    Termwind\ValueObjects\mb_strimwidth()`
 at vendor/nunomaduro/termwind/src/ValueObjects/Styles.php:1053


 1049▕  */
 `    private static function trimText(string $text, int $width): string
        {
              preg_match_all(self::STYLING_REGEX, $text, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
           $text = rtrim(mb_strimwidth(preg_replace(self::STYLING_REGEX, '',         $text) ?? '', 0, $width, '', 'UTF-8'));                                                                     
  
             foreach ($matches[0] ?? [] as [$part, $index]) {
              $text = substr($text, 0, $index).$part.substr($text, $index, null);
        }`
  

+4 vendor frames 
  5 [internal]:0
 `Termwind\Components\Element::__toString()`
 +23 vendor frames 
 29  artisan:35
 `Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()`
```

Answer (score 0):

### If you face the same problem which I show you then you can follow this step

Just open your linux debian terminal in your root and paste the three command one by one-----

---Step 1:
`wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libo/libonig/libonig4_6.7.0-1_amd64.deb`

---Step 2:
`sudo dpkg -i libonig4_6.7.0-1_amd64.deb`

---Step 3:
`sudo apt-get install php7.4-mbstring`

Comment: Hi, look carefully at the question: there was an attempt to install php8.2